# Inserting multiple images in Excel using OpenPyxel does not work

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to insert images with OpenPyxl to a Excel file that has already images in it (in different sheets in my case). If I do so, the existing images disappear.

Sample code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws1 = wb.create_sheet("MySheet1")
img1 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test1.png')
img1.anchor = ws1.cell(row=2, column=2).coordinate
ws1.add_image(img1)
wb.save('test_output.xlsx')

wb = load_workbook(filename='test_output.xlsx')
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("MySheet2")
img2 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test2.png')
img2.anchor = ws2.cell(row=2, column=2).coordinate
ws2.add_image(img2)
wb.save('test_output.xlsx')
```

Is there anything I do wrong here?

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

As stated in the comments this should work now:

> Up until very recently images in existing files were not preserved.
>   You   need >= 2.5.5 for this.

The doc states for older versions:

> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file
>   so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are
>   opened and saved with the same name.

There are several bug issues about this ([here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/189/image-insert-in-excel-erases-existing), [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/870/losing-images-after-loading-and-saving-a), [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/523/charts-in-existing-worksheets-lost))

One [comment](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/189/image-insert-in-excel-erases-existing#comment-23793200) in the issues is using `win32com` as a workaround to copy the sheet with the image to a different file.

Comment: I am currently using version 2.4.0, one of the issues states that charts are handled correctly in 2.5.0.

Comment: I just got the answer from the great Charlie Clark in [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openpyxl-users/0_q2T-icXPU/ZkEVe1rmCQAJ) that one needs version>= 2.5.5 for preserving images during openPyxl modification.